# Rails association with 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 6. Here's what I want to achieve:

- Shop has many reviews.
- A review belongs to one Profile.
- Profile has many reviews.
- Profile can only have one review for a shop.
- Profile cannot have more than one review for a shop.

Here's my association that is not working:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :profile, counter_cache: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
end
```

What is not working here is - as a `current_user` (with `profile`, hence `current_user.profile`), how do I get a shop's review of the current user? Technically should return one review.

Comment: What associations are there in your `User` model?

Comment: @gautam Added to the question.

Comment: Is this not working?
`current_user.profile.reviews.where(shop: shop)` or `current_user.profile.reviews.where(shop_id: shop_id)`

Comment: It works, but is there other way to write this, without passing the shop object manually?

Comment: If you want to get the review of a single shop you would have to provide the `shop object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reviews, through: :profile
end

current_user.reviews.find_by(shop: @shop)
```

Or

```
@shop.reviews.find_by(profile: current_user.profile)
```

This assumes you have actually added a compound index on `reviews.shop_id` and `reviews.profile_id` to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on the uniqueness. I will add `add_index :reviews, [:review_id, :profile_id], unique: true`.

Comment: Adding the index makes sure your database is correct, but if you do not add a corresponding (rails) validation, handling the error gets a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, in the code you showed, there is no limitation for a user (via a profile) to give multiple reviews for the same shop (which might also be correct/wanted, since over time their review could change?).

You seem to be looking for an "easy"/shorter way to retrieve the review(s) for a shop the current-user has given? However, since you need to find the reviews for a specific combination (of user and shop), you will always need to filter both on shop and profile.

Options:

- `current_shop.reviews.where(profile_id: current_user.profile_id)`
- `Review.where(shop_id: current_shop.id, profile_id: current_user.profile_id)`
- `current_user.profile.reviews.where(shop_id: current_shop.id)`

These will all return an array of reviews. You could add `.first` or `.last` to make sure to get the `review` directly  (if you are sure there is only one, or are only  interested in the latest review for instance).

You could define a method on `User` to provide some kind of shorthand:

```
class User 

  def review_for(shop) 
    profile.reviews.where(shop_id: shop.id).last 
  end 
end
```

which would return the last (most recent) review for that shop the user has made. And then you could just write

```
current_user.review_for(current_shop)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. A user should only have one review of a shop. He can edit it later anyways.

Comment: You can enforce through validations that there should be only one, but I would prefer enforcing it through your UI (always show one and allow to edit that one, and only allow to create a new one if there was none).